# Empty body in fetch POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, cors, fetch-api

I'm struggling with the fetch API in Javascript.
When I try to POST something to my server with `fetch` method, the request body contains an empty array. But when I use Postman it works.
Here is my server-side code in Node.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.json())
app.post('/api', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
})
app.listen(port)
```

Here is my client-side code:

```
fetch('http://"theserverip":3000/api', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    mode: 'no-cors',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'dean',
        login: 'dean',
    })
})
.then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
})
```

The problem is that the `req.body` is empty on server side.

Comment: Are you saying that the response from your express server is empty? Or is the request on the server empty?

Comment: The request on the server is empty.

Comment: seems a valid request, your server might be unable to parse it. check on server what it is expecting.

Comment: Why `mode: 'no-cors'`?

Comment: I use no-cors mode because without it i have a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error. But I just saw your response, thank you i will investigate on how to solve this error without using this mode.

Comment: It seems like the browser is changing content type to `text/plain`

Comment: I am not specifying mode = no-cors, and I have the same problem

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The issue is

```
mode: 'no-cors'
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode#Value)...

> Prevents the method from being anything other than HEAD, GET or POST, **and the headers from being anything other than [simple headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#simple-header)**

These are `accept`, `accept-language`, `content-language`, `content-type` and `range`.

The *simple* content-type header restriction allows the values

- `text/plain`,
- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and
- `multipart/form-data`

This causes your nicely crafted `Content-Type: application/json` header to become `content-type: text/plain` (at least when tested through Chrome).

Since your Express server is expecting JSON, it won't parse this request.

I recommend omitting the `mode` config. This uses the default `"cors"` option instead.

---

Since your request is not [*simple*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests), you'll probably want to add some [CORS middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) to your Express server.

Another (slightly hacky) option is to tell Express to parse `text/plain` requests as JSON. This allows you to send JSON strings as simple requests which can also avoid a pre-flight `OPTIONS` request, thus lowering the overall network traffic...

```
app.use(express.json({
  type: ['application/json', 'text/plain']
}))
```

EDIT: Added ending parenthesis to `app.use` final code block.

Comment: Finally! I got it just adding cors lib "yarn add cors" and in file app.js, I added: app.use(cors()).
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but 2nd method did work for me with `xml`.

Comment: That's was extremely evasive to detect!

Answer (score 4):

To complement the excellent answers that mentioned removing the `mode: 'no-cors'` option, and if you don't feel like adding a [CORS middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) to Express, you may just want to handle "pre-flight" requests under an `OPTIONS` block:

```
app.options('*', (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type'); // Add other headers here
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST'); // Add other methods here
  res.send();
});
```

Another nice answer here : https://www.vinaygopinath.me/blog/tech/enable-cors-with-pre-flight/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why would you opt for an incomplete CORS implementation over the industry standard middleware?

Answer (score 3):

Please see document [mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode), `no-cors` mode only send simple headers. So the content-Type is changed to `text/html;` instead of `application/json` so your server can't recognize body format and return empty.

Remove `mode: 'no-cors',` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

none seems to work for me I solved this issue using middleware

```
app.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());
```

or

```
app.use(multer().array())
```

Answer (score -1):

Many of the above answers weren't resolving my issue, so anyone running into this problem may need to do what I needed to do and enable their `app` to be capable of reading JSON in a body, as the app can't do that by default which is what's leading to the empty body

I resolved this by adding:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

POST/PUT requests sent the body no problem after adding this one line

Technically, the `bodyParser` module is deprecated, so this isn't the most ideal solution, but if adding the above line to your code makes it work then you at least know your issue lies in the way your app can parse/read JSON in a body